# ElasticBeanstalk failing to build Go application with modules with no explanation

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The environment was creating with all the defaults and the sample application
I am trying to launch the following setup on ElasticBeanstalk

```
application.go
go.mod
go.sum
```

application.go consists of the following

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
)

func main() {
    app := fiber.New()

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        return c.SendString("Hello World!")
    })

    app.Listen(":" + os.Getenv("PORT"))
}
```

I zip these files and upload it directly into my environment; this fails without any details as to why.
This is the complete log https://pastebin.com/F8iRUwhV

It works perfectly if you don't use go modules. I can't find anything in the documentation related to this.

Comment: This log looks relevant: `{"msg":"Instance deployment: You didn't include a 'go.mod' file in your source bundle. Elastic Beanstalk set the 'GOPATH' environment property to the application path.","timestamp":1636484223,"severity":"INFO"}`

Comment: @Gavin Sorry the log still contains information from the sample application deployment. If you scroll down slightly you'll see my deployment at a different time with `found go.mod file`. I've edited those logs to only include my deployment

Comment: Does the application build locally without error?  Elastic Beanstalk uses the build command `go build -o bin/application application.go`.

Comment: @fedonev yes it builds and runs fine